# User defined function nor working in H2 database

Tags: java, h2

I've got this Java function that normalises a String:

```
public static Object normalizeString(String source) {
    if (source==null) return null;
    String cleaned = source.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\t]", "");
    cleaned = Normalizer.normalize(cleaned, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    cleaned = cleaned.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""); // on vire tout ce qui n'est pa ascii
    cleaned = cleaned.strip();
    return cleaned;
}
```

And I'm calling it at 2 places in my application:

Once in a upgrade SQL script:

```
alter table entry add infostr1S VARCHAR_IGNORECASE null;
CREATE ALIAS normalizeString FOR "com.zparkingb.zploger.Compute.NormalizationSupport.normalizeString";
update entry set infostr1S = normalizeString(infostr1) where infostr1 is not null;
```

Once in a AFTER INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE trigger:

```
public class TriggerUpdateEntry implements Trigger {
    // ...
    public void fire(Connection conn, Object[] oldRow, Object[] newRow) throws SQLException {
        if (newRow == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Normalisation of the searchable strings on INSERT et UPDATE
        newRow[34] = NormalizationSupport.normalizeString((String) newRow[20]); //instr1 
    }
}
```

While the TRIGGERs are working correctly, the UPDATEs don't work : all the cleaned columns are containing a strange string looking like "**aced0005740011523230305f4475206c6f7572642e677078**".

[EDIT]: More investigations on when it works, when it does not:

- with the BEFORE UPDATE trigger **active**, all the values are correct.
- with the BEFORE UPDATE trigger **dropped**, all the values are incorrect.

This means, IMO, that

```
CREATE ALIAS normalizeString FOR "com.zparkingb.zploger.Compute.NormalizationSupport.normalizeString";
update entry set infostr1S = normalizeString(infostr1) where infostr1 is not null;
```

does not work properly.

Could this be related to the way that script is called or the function is defined ?

```
for (Path scriptPath : scripts) {
    try (Statement st = archive.getConnection().createStatement()) {
        logger.info("Executing update script " + scriptPath);
        st.execute("RUNSCRIPT FROM '" + scriptPath + "'");
        logger.debug("Script " + scriptPath + " executed");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DBException("Execution of script " + scriptPath + " failed", ex);
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this already ?

PS: I'm using H2.1.4.196 (last version with the old file format) and Java 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the normalization function which return-signature is `Object`.

When called from java, there is no problem because the actual return type is `String`. But when called from H2 as an Alias Function, the `Object` return-signature is confusing H2 that then serializes the value into that "aced000574001152323030"-type string.

Explicitly changing the return-signature to `String` prevents that confusion and solves the issue:

```
public static String normalizeString(String source) {
    if (source==null) return null;
    String cleaned = source.replaceAll("[\\n\\r\\t]", "");
    cleaned = Normalizer.normalize(cleaned, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    cleaned = cleaned.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""); // on vire tout ce qui n'est pa ascii
    cleaned = cleaned.strip();
    return cleaned;
}
```